# Apache mod_rewrite with variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to modify my .htaccess in order to perfom the next redirect:

http://www.example.com/en/region1/subregion1/subregion2

to

http://www.example.com/en/example.php?param1=region1&param2=subregion1&param3=subregion2

The problem for me is that the original URL can have this 3 different structures:

/region1/

/region1/subregion1/

/region1/subregion1/subregion2

What I want is to convert this subdirectories in variables, whether they are 3 or only 1.

How can I achieve this with mod_rewrite?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a base:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/(([^/]+)/)(([^/]+)/)?(([^/]+)/)?$ example.php?param1=$2&param2=$4&param3=$6
```

URL with only one param will be targeted to

```
example.php?param1=region1&param2=&param3=
```

So, non-existing params will be empty.